# Why does the code to find factorial in sh does not work?

Tags: sh

```
    echo " enter the number "
read a
fact = 1
while [ $a -gt 1 ]

    do
        fact = ` expr $fact \* $a ` 
        a = ` expr $a - 1 `
        done
        echo " factorial of given number is $fact"
```

I want to find the factorial of a number.
The output shown is

```
expr: syntax error
abc: 7: abc: fact: not found
abc: 8: abc: a: not found
```

Comment: Use `$((...))` for arithmetic instead of the external `expr` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assignments [cannot not have spaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/258727/spaces-in-assignments-in-shell-scripts) before or after the `=`, otherwise they are interpreted as commands or assign no value:

```
echo " enter the number "
read a
fact=1
while [ $a -gt 1 ]
do
  fact=`expr $fact \* $a`
  a=`expr $a - 1 `
done
echo " factorial of given number is $fact"
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I'll accept the answer when it allows me to do so